# Difference between file and classes in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, development-environment

I am a bit confuse that where to use file or class in kotlin can some one please suggest when to use file,it is not clear for me due to less documents for both the case.

Comment: If you mean creating new stuff from within Android Studio, "class" sets up an empty Kotlin class for you based on the filename; "file" does not. Otherwise, they are equivalent.

Comment: Kotlin file can have different classes or methods

Answer (score 2):

You got to use a kotlin file to declare extension methods , and import that file to the class or file you're working on

Eg: the kotlin file contains

```
package com.something.mediaplayersystem

public fun String.toLowerCaseByAnExtensionMethod(){
    this.toLowerCase()
}
```

And I want to use that extension method on a class

```
package com.something.mediaplayersystem

import com.something.mediaplayersystem.toLowerCase

class Classa {
    var word:String = "WELCOME"

    public fun Method(){
        var lowerCaseWord = word.toLowerCaseByAnExtensionMethod()
    }
}
```

In the case of String you don't need to import the method but in mayor cases you have to.

Comment: Okay, just to confirm you mean we can use file for extention function but I guess classes can be used for same purpose, so is there any benefits of files using for this purpose or its is just as per the architecture of kotlin. Also please share some other advantage if you know other than this. Thanks

Comment: Just as per the architecture of kotlin , you can use a class but it’s most common to use files